# SSRS Expression to Sum value IIF YearMonth = Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I hope someone would be able to assist\help.

I have a Tablix that I'm trying to populate with three separate (summed) values (Current Month, Current Year and Previous Year) from one field based on a parameter.  My parameter is set as `yyyymm`.  My expression logic is as follows for each summed value:

Sum Current Month values

`=SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value),IIF(Parameters!YearMonth.Value) = CDATE(Now()), "yyyyMM")`

Sum Current Year values

`=SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value),IIF(Parameters!YearMonth.Value) = CDATE(Now()), "yyyy")`

Sum Previous Year values

`=SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value),IIF(Parameters!YearMonth.Value) = CDATE(Now()), "yyyy")-1`

I'm getting the following error when attempting the above expressions:

The Value expression for the textrun `Quantity5.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]` contains an error: `[BC30205] End of statement expected`

Comment: shouldn't the Iff part come first? =iif(somecondition, truepart,falsepart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Harry pointed out, the IIF statement syntax is

```
IIF([Expression to evalute], [Expression to return if true], [Expression to return if false])
```

Also, I think you need to format the date you get back from `now()` so it matches the format of your parameter.

So, taking your first expression it should be something like

```
=SUM(
    IIF(Parameters!YearMonth.Value = FORMAT(Now(), "yyyyMM"), Fields!Quantity.Value, Nothing)
    )
```

So starting at the inner expression, we compare the parameter to today's date formatted as `yyyyMM`. If the match the return the value of the `Quantity` field, if not return nothing.
The outer SUM then just sums all these results.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you both Harry and Alan.  I'm a bit new to SSRS and have worked with expressions in the past but trying to get the above right has been a challenge for the past 2 weeks.  I appreciate your help and guidance.